# Free/commercial PDF Viewer component .NET or Activex

Tags: .net, pdf, activex, components, viewer

I'm looking for a solid and reasonably priced (under 500 USD) PDF viewing component for using in a .NET application. It can be a native .NET control or ActiveX one.

It has to support the following features:

1. No Adobe dependencies
2. Search function
3. Printing

Are there any products to match this criteria?

Comment: Why do you have the requirement not to be dependent on Adobe products? (such as Acrobat Reader, which fulfils your other requirements)

Comment: It's going to be a portable application, installing Reader isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDFView4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdfview4net/overview.htm) satisfies your requirements, #1, #2 and #3.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops PDFView4NET.

Comment: Hi Sorin, thanks for your reply. I've downloaded PDFView4NET trial and really like it. Unfortunately, $700 is more than I can currently afford. Do you have any discount policies for SO users? :)

Comment: @Sphynx - send an email to sales and they will help you.